# Linq Any() vs foreach

Tags: c#

Just wonder which approach is faster and better to use or which do you prefer

```
bool userHavePermission = user.Permissions.Any(x => x.UpperName == "ADMINISTRATOR");
```

or

```
foreach (Permission p in _Permissions)
{
    if (p.UpperName == name.ToUpper())
       return true;
}
return false;
```

Thanks

Comment: effectively, it's the same code; `Any` iterates over the `IEnumerable` applying the predicate, returning true (and stopping iteration) on the first match. That said, I'd pick `Any`, since it is very clear what the code is trying to do.

Comment: Did you try comparing the resulting IL code? Or, if different, the resulting jitted code?

Comment: The question is entirely subjective and not constructive which makes it not appropriate for SO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's almost same code, the only difference being that with the second code snippet you're gonna get a `NullReferenceException` at runtime if the `name` variable is `null` because you will be calling the `.ToUpper()` method on a null instance. The first looks shorter, safer and more readable, it's what I would use. And to ensure that there won't be any NREs:

```
return user
    .Permissions
    .Any(x => string.Equals(x.UpperName, name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Any is the better approach as it is one line.  It reads easier and takes up less space.

Additionally it is unclear what the Permissions object is but if it's a entity of somekind representing a database table then Any is definitely better as you only return the result of the query where the foreach is going to resolve the entire list of Permissions before the iteration begins.